# Laravel9 can not write in Docker directory

Tags: laravel, docker, permissions

I have a local Docker container with Laravel application. This app need to write html template to /application/storage/framework/views directory but it throws me an error
**file_put_contents(/application/storage/framework/views/fd2df5443235b715e713e31b780d95a013867ee8.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied**
So I checked the permissions on all of the directories and found out that all of them are owned by root/root with 777 and top directory is owned by root with 755 rwxrxrx. so I changed the permissions to 777. Look at the picture. But it is still the same error. Can somebody tell me please what permisions I need to set up?

[image]

**EDIT**
Hmm weird is that when I deleted the files in Windows directory which is mounted to the container, it start to work. I dont understand it.